# Тест по Linux и Python

Tags: python, linux

Готовлюсь к тестам, нашла тренировочные разные. Почти все прошла, но не могу ответить на указанные ниже вопросы. Помогите, пожалуйста...

1. Импорт модуля *.py в Python возможен командой:

- a. import os
- b. import os as new
- c. import os as os
- d. import system from os
- e. import os as init

2. Какой из форматов команд позволяет создать структуру из четырех
   основных логических разделов:

- a. fdisk /dev/hdb
- b. gdisk /dev/hdb1
- c. fdisk /dev/hdb2
- d. gdisk /dev/hdb1
- e. gdisk /dev/hdb

3. Kонструкция:

```
def new_f ():
    print ("This function is new")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_f ()
```

выводит текст на экран в случае:

- a. Запуска интерпретатору в автономном модуле.
- b. Вызова во внешнем модуле.
- c. Запуска в автономном и внешнем модуле
- d. Вызова функции во внешнем модуле
- e. Вызова метода в автономном внешнем модуле

4. Направить поток вывода одного процесса на поток ввода другого
   позволяет команда:

- a. `>`
- b. `<`
- c. `|`
- d. `||`
- e. `>>`

Comment: откройте книгу по питону и башу. Это базовые вопросы. Если Вы их не можете пройти, то я не знаю, что Вы смогли пройти. вопрос 1 - элементарный, посмотрите в любую книгу по питону. вопрос 2 - тут нужно узнать, что у Вас в методичке написано, вопрос 3 - тут явно надо исправить сам вопрос. А в 4 - тут  палочка, очевидно.

Comment: А почему бы не проверить на практике?

Comment: второй вопрос я бы не проверял без подготовки

Comment: Дело в том, что все остальные вопросы только по Linux и на них ответила без проблем. А тут пошел Python и начались проблемы...

Comment: 2 и 4 вопрос - по "линуксу".

Comment: сложные, поэтому и кинула сюда

Comment: @Mariana Matviienko -   " пошел Python и начались проблемы..." -  ну, значит надо читать книжки по Python. Ответы на эти вопросы обычно почти в самом их начале.

Comment: в общем, решила так:

Comment: 1 А
2 А
3 А
4 С (как мне Вы помогли)
Не уверена, что это правильно правда...

Comment: правдоподобно. но второй вопрос - под большим вопросом.

Comment: В первом вопросе можно выбрать несколько вариантов? Так-то всё кроме d возможно. Но нормальный способ а.

Comment: Что удивительно, так это второй вопрос с двумя правильными ответами и четвёртый тоже, если знать про /dev/fd.

Comment: @KoVadim, если есть виртуалка, то цена ошибки стремится к нулю. Я вообще ничего не ставлю и не тестю на реальной машине уже лет 7 наверное.

Comment: главное запускать на виртуалке. а то наличие виртуальной машины ещё не значит, что на ней будет тестирование. (тестю - это отцу жены, если что:) )

Comment: Ну так-то - да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `a`
2. `a`
3. `a`
4. `с`

В первом вопросе некорректная формулировка. "Возможно" сильно отличается от "правильно" и "надо".
В действительности вы МОЖЕТЕ сделать импорт модуля всеми предложенными вариантами, кроме `d`, но это бессмысленно. Среди них ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ только `a`.

Конструкция `import numpy as np` используется зачастую для сокращения имени импортируемого объекта модуля.
Как пример `from module import some_very_very_long_function as short_name`)

Так же формулировка в 3 вопросе некорректна.
Конструкция типа

```
# script.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # код для исполнения
```

сработает только если данный файл является первичным запускаемым файлом, т.е. команда запуска `python script.py`
Если вы импортируете этот файл во внешнем модуле, код из данной конструкции не сработает.